# LINQ query to find common strings between two collections

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following distinct two collections:

```
IQueryable<Book> allBooks = context.Books.Where(b => b.UserID == hostID);

var visBookTitles = context.Books.Where(b => b.UserID == visitorID)
.Select(b =>b.Title.ToLower()).ToList();
```

What would be the most efficient way (using method syntax, preferably) to return all the books from `allBooks` that share a common title with any of the titles from `visBookTitles` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
var bookTitles = new HashSet<string>(visBookTitles, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
var someBooks = allBooks.AsEnumerable().Where(b => bookTitles.Contains(b.Title));
```

You should also get rid of the `ToLower` call.  (`StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` is faster and handles messy Unicode situations)

Comment: Do you need the `AsEnumerable()`? Can't you use the `Where` extension on `IQueryable<T>`?

Comment: @RPM: I'm assuming that he's using LINQ to SQL or EF, in which case using `IQueryable<T>` would throw an exception because it cannot be translated to SQL.

Comment: Ahh, k - fair enough. Figured this was regular LINQ-Objects.

Comment: You'd have to write out the where clause however.  `...Where(b => bookTitles.Contains(b.Title));`.  `allBooks` is `IEnumerable<Book>` and there is no `Contains()` method that takes a `Book` for `HashSet<string>`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Intersect()` if the items in the collections should be considered equal or `Join()` if they only share certain properties.  In your case, you're intersecting books vs titles so `Join()` is most appropriate.

```
var query = allBooks.Join(visBookTitles,
                          book => book.Title,
                          title => title,
                          (book, title) => book);
```